# Manter dados entre sessões

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, session

Tenho um projeto ASP.NETet MVC onde gero um relatório que exige bastante recurso da máquina em questão de processamento.

Tenho uma `Action` que gera e outra que devolve os dados do relatório em uma Lista de Objetos, então achei que criando uma variável estática, eu poderia guardar os dados do relatório e devolve-los quando necessário.

```
private static List<MeuObjeto> DadosRelatorio = new List<MeuObjeto>();
public ActionResult MinhaAction ()
{
    // Limpando dados que já estavam.
    if (DadosRelatorio.Count() > 0)
    {
        DadosRelatorio.Clear();
    }

    ...
    // Preenchendo DadosRelatorio
    ...
}
public ActionResult OutraAction ()
{
  return Json(DadosRelatorio, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

O problema é que quando 2 ou mais usuários geram simultaneamente um relatório, os dados de um sobrescrevem o de outro.

Pensei que ao criar uma variável estática o próprio *framework* gerenciaria uma variável para cada um no servidor, mas não é isso que acontece, a mesma variável está para todos os usuário.

Existe alguma alternativa?

Comment: Bastante recurso quanto? Milhões de linhas?

Comment: Exatamente @CiganoMorrisonMendez , milhões de linhas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

De fato a variável estática não pode ser usada. Você precisa criar um sistema de cache baseado na sessão ou pelo menos manter a informação dentro da mesma sessão.

```
public ActionResult MinhaAction() {
    Session["relatorioX"] = MontaRelatorio();
    ...
}
public ActionResult OutraAction() => Json(Session["relatorioX"], JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/Session.cs).

O `MontaRelatorio()` provavelmente devolve um `List<MeuObjeto>`.

Isto obviamente é uma simplificação, podem ocorrer erros se usado assim mas faz o que você estava fazendo mantendo os dados por sessão ao invés de manter por instância da aplicação.

Acredito que neste caso pode usar `TempData` ao invés de `Session` sem problemas.

Não sei se isto atende todas as necessidades mas resolve o problema de acordo com o que foi especificado na pergunta.

Eu evitaria colocar uma quantidade grande dados entre sessões mas é uma solução simples.

Essa [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/968873/221800) tem uma solução com cache. [Outra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20801643/221800) usando o próprio sistema de cache do *framework*.

O ASP.NET Core tem um [novo sistema de cache](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching) mais flexível ([exemplo de uso](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching)).

Comment: é uma ótima solução, mas realmente tenho uma grande quantidade de dados para armazenar, isto me causaria problemas?

Comment: Pode tornar o sistema um pouco lento mas obviamente é um ganho substancial em relação a gerar tudo de novo. Na verdade talvez você nem perceba problemas de performance. teste e me diga como se saiu.

Comment: percebi que o `TempData` fica "vivo" por pouco tempo, acho que a `Session` seria a única alternativa para resolver esse problema mesmo. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: É, ela não resolve se precisa manter por mais tempo.

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Outra alternative é usar uma cache de documentos, como o Couchbase.

Comment: Cria um sistema de sessao no banco de dados, cria uma variagem unica que identifica aquela sessao e os dados em questao

Answer (score 1):

Uma sugestão:  utilize nomes diferentes para os relatórios, baseados nos identificadores dos usuários (se aplicável), onde voce possa, através de um BATCH que rode 1x ao dia, deletar os relatorios mais antigos baseados em suas datas (se aplicável).

Desta forma voce possuirá relatórios "user-dependent" (aumentando o uso em disco obviamente), sem depender exclusivamente de variaveis perenes.

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele.

Comment: Perdoe-me, mas minha postagem oferece uma solução alternativa, dentro do contexto maior que ele deseja: oferecer um método não-perene de manter dados de relatórios. Da mesma forma, minha dica não é uma crítica nem pedido de esclarecimento. Logo, entendo ser esta a forma correta de oferecer soluções - não necessariamente a solução que, do jeito que ele está fazendo e outros esclareceram, não será cumprida.