# Limitação de Session para guardar dados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, session

Tenho um *query* lenta no Oracle para listar todos os acessos de um usuário, então pensei em gravar o resultado em uma `Session`, a media de registros retornados é 600, é muito para uma `Session`?

Teria alguma outra forma melhor de se guardar esses dados?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não tem uma questão de ser muito para a sessão, pode ser muito para a memória que você tem disponível. Se você tiver 600 registros na sessão, é pouco. Se se você tiver 1000 sessões simultâneas, 600 mil pode ser muito, pode não ser.

Eu [respondi algo sobre isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/86695/101), ali falo que a melhor solução é um sistema de cache. Ele é mais adequado na maioria das situações porque pode ser liberado se necessário e dura além das sessões, que em muitos cenários pode ser um ganho interessante. Lá eu falo para não exagerar na carga da `session`. Mas falo de exagerar mesmo. E o tamanho do exagero depende da memória disponível.

Lembre-se que o banco de dados tem um cache também (veja como implementar na resposta do OnoSendai). Pode ser que ele seja suficiente também. Mediu para ver se realmente precisa manter algo em memória? Tem ganho razoável? Sem medir não dá para afirmar nada. Mesmo que seja intuitivo, às vezes, na prática, pode ocorrer algo diferente do esperado.

Se perceber que precisa de um outro nível de cache, procure uma solução em memória no mesmo servidor. Isto deve resolver 99,99% dos casos. Se você tem um caso raro na mão e precisa escalar horizontalmente, procure um software que ajude nisto, tipo um [Memcached](http://memcached.org/), [Redis](http://redis.io/), etc.

Há um [*framework* que ajuda nisto](http://cachemanager.net/) e possui diversas opções. Na página deles confirma que o cache mais simples é o mais rápido e que bancos de dados servem mais quando há necessidade de distribuição entre processos (onde a performance é absurdamente inferior, ao ponto de ser pouco útil como cache em alguns cenários). O uso de dicionário também é o que ocupa menos memória, o que é útil para dar espaço para mais conteúdo útil.

Answer (score 8):

> A média de registros retornados é 600, é muito para uma Session?

Não. *Sessions* em teoria não possuem limite de armazenamento.

> Teria alguma outra forma melhor de se guardar esses dados?

Sim, em um servidor de presistência chave-valor, como o [Redis](http://redis.io/). *Sessions* te limitam a apenas um servidor, enquanto que o Redis pode atendê-lo em um contexto distribuído.

Answer (score 8):

Como Cigano e Maniero disseram, não, não há limites.

Porém se seu problema é performance em uma base de dados Oracle, eu tenho uma sugestão: [*Materialized Views*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/basicmv.htm#DWHSG0082).

Uma *Materialized View* é basicamente um *snapshot* de uma *query* cacheada no banco de dados, que pode ser indexada.

Este é um exemplo de criação de *Materialized View*:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_LOGINS_USUARIO_52
NOLOGGING
CACHE
BUILD IMMEDIATE 
REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT 
AS
[Sua query aqui]
```

Uma vez criada, a view conterá o resultado da última consulta até que seja destruída ou refrescada. Como você não está executando a *query* de novo, mas apenas acessando dados cacheados, o tempo de resposta é muito superior.

A vantagem deste método é que você não consome recursos do servidor web.

Comment: Gostei da solução =D, mas ainda prefiro redis

Comment: @Rod eu prefiro Redis para outras coisas. Se não há necessidade de cache distribuído, a adição de um serviço apenas para guardar cache de consulta é desnecessária.

Comment: bem pelo contrário, usar o redis para deixar dados de db, dependendo da disponibilidade, é ótimo, já pensou se for uma tabela que há pouca ou nenhuma mudança(valores fixos) e sendo bem acessada por um grande número de usuários? ficaria muito de boa =D. Por curiosidade, em quais casos você utiliza o redis? Se não para armazenar dados..rsrs

Comment: @Rod como mencionei, uso Redis para cache distribuído. Se não há necessidade de coordenar o cache entre vários servidores - ou, como no caso do OP, o conteúdo a ser cacheado por ser centralizado no banco de dados mesmo - então a adição de um serviço extra não é justificável; existem várias camadas disponíveis nativamente (System.Web.Caching, System.Runtime.Caching, MemoryCache, etc.) Uma boa arquitetura possui o mínimo de partes móveis necessário.

Comment: Gostaria de ver mais perguntas/respostas sobre o assunto, parece algo muito interessante e útil. +1