# Armazenar dados temporariamente em ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net

Preciso armazenar algumas strings temporariamente em uma aplicação em ASP.NET MVC, essas strings precisam ser acessíveis pelo *server-side* da aplicação a qualquer momento e a própria aplicação ficará encarregada de se desfazer dessas strings armazenadas.

Qual é a maneira ideal de realizar isso em ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Quando você se refere ao servidor seria onde a aplicação esta hospedada? ou outra aplicação que vai acessar? Ta um pouco confuso isso ai.

Comment: Só um servidor? O volume é grande? Temporário quanto? Enquanto durar a sessão? Dê mais contexto.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza editei a pergunta, servidor = server-side da aplicação, escrevi apenas para deixar claro que quero ter acesso aos dados a qualquer momento, como se eu estivesse consultando um banco de dados.

Comment: @bigown por que teria mais de um servidor? Sobre o volume, como eu disse, é apenas uma string, ela é basicamente um id. Sobre o tempo da sessão, como eu disse, a aplicação irá gerenciar quando a string será excluída desse "storage".

Comment: Então esse `id` pode sobreviver por várias sessões? Só por ter um `id`desse de cada vez no servidor? É um dado "estático" da aplicação e não da sessão, ele não é bem temporário, ele é apenas desnecessário a todo momento?

Comment: Sim, ele pode sobreviver por várias sessões. Mas não ficará armazenado para sempre na aplicação. No meu caso, esse dado tem um tempo de vida menor que 3 horas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviamente tem várias soluções e sem saber cada detalhe eu não saberia afirmar qual o melhor.

Se basta estar na aplicação corrente pode usar o estado no [`HttpContext.Application`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.application?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) (Veja também o [objeto de estado](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplicationstate?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)). Isto é apenas um dicionário específico que pode guardar qualquer dado. [Exemplo de uso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3733549/221800). E [exemplos aplicados](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5286301/221800).

Outros mecanismos mais manuais podem ser usados, alguns baseados no sistema de cache.

Se precisa de algo externo à aplicação poderia ser até um serviço que armazene isto em memória, mas tem solução mais simples que deve atender aos requisitos. Jogue em um arquivo que pode ser lido. Duvido que ache uma solução mais simples.

Se tiver problemas de concorrência de quem vai escrever isto e não quiser lidar por conta própria no arquivo jogue em um banco de dados, mesmo que seja o SQLite. Muitos já optariam por isso por padrão. Se já usa ele, pode ser até melhor mesmo. Se usa um banco de dados (provavelmente), criar uma tabela com uma coluna e uma linha é tão simples que não vejo por que não fazer (poderia ter algum motivo, mas nada descrito indica isto).

Tem soluções mais complexas, mas desnecessárias.

[Algo que pode ajudar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89943/101).